# LMDMapiSendMail1 - send printscreen as attachment

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe6

After 'print screen' I paste the image into cxImage component.

How can I tell LMDMapiSendMail1 (from lmdinnovative) component to send the contents of the cxImage as an attachment ?

Comment: mhhh.. quite broad ...

Comment: You need to save the image to a temp file and then tell Mapi the path and filename.

Comment: I thought as much ...you are right Remy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since LMDMapiSendMail1 deals attachments as files, like Remy said, one must save the file first. I found a nice example of saving printscreen to file (Mike Shkolnik). Applied it to cxImage1 properties change:

```
procedure TForm11.cxImage1PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
var DCDesk: HDC;
bmp: TBitmap;
begin
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
  bmp.Height := Screen.Height;
  bmp.Width := Screen.Width;
  DCDesk := GetWindowDC(GetDesktopWindow);
  BitBlt(bmp.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Screen.Width, Screen.Height,
         DCDesk, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
  bmp.SaveToFile('ScreenShot.bmp');
  ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow, DCDesk);
  bmp.Free;
end;
```

It saves the file in the application.exe folder. Now all thet is left to do is to tell 
LMDMapiSendMail1 where the file is and add it as attachment like:

> LMDMapiSendMail1.Attachment.Append('ScreenShot.bmp');

Not very elegant but it works.

edit:
However,I simplified everything (after I pasted the pic in the cxImage1) with a button click:

```
procedure TForm11.AdvGlowButton2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
cxImage1.Properties.GraphicClassName:='TJPEGImage';
cxImage1.picture.SaveToFile(extractfilepath(application.ExeName)+'picture.jpg');
end;
```

Then just did :

```
procedure TForm11.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var Path: String;
begin
Path:= ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
LMDMapiSendMail1.Attachment.Append(Path + 'picture.jpg');
end;
```

Much simpler ...